# After using separate function, I cannot create a new dataframe with the new columns

Tags: r

I used the separate function to split one column of scores into 4. For example "66-67-69-67" into "66 67 69 67," with corresponding names of 'R1', 'R2', 'R3','R4.' I run the line, and it shows exactly what I want. But after that, when I want to have a new dataframe with those columns, the error "object R1 not found" comes up.

```
df <- data.frame(rank,player,score,total,par)
separate(df, score, c('R1', 'R2','R3','R4'), sep="\\-")
rank                        player  R1   R2   R3   R4 total par
1                      So Yeon Ryu  64   67   69    67   267 -21
2                  Caroline Masson  67   66   68    68   269 -19
3                         Lydia Ko  69   67   67    67   270 -18
```

But then when I create new dataframe, using below code, I get the error

```
df.rd <- data.frame(rank,player,R1, R2, R3, R4, total)
head(df)
Error in data.frame(rank, player, R1, R2, R3, R4, total) : 
  object 'R1' not found
```

Comment: Please show the input example using `dput` and the expected output base do that example.  Have you updated the initial dataset identifier with the output i.e `df <- separate(df, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun pointed out, rank, player and total are standalone objects but R1 et. al are not. They have to be called from the parent dataframe. Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(rank,player,score,total,par)
ab <- separate(df, score, c('R1', 'R2','R3','R4'), sep="\\-")
```

Now the new data frame:

```
df.rd <- data.frame(rank,player, ab$R1, ab$R2, ab$R3, ab$R4, total)
head(df)
```